# Best xml validator in nodejs

Tags: xml, node.js

Hi I am trying to check if the xml data is a valid one or not in nodejs.I used the xmldoc module but it didnt seem to throw me any error when i passed a wrong xml data.
I also tried xmltojson parser below is my code

```
 var xml2js = require('xml2js')
 var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
 parser.on('end', function(POST_VALUE) {
 console.log(POST_VALUE)
 });
 parser.parseString(POST_VALUE);
```

In POST_VALUE i passed a invalid xml still it didnt throw me any error but did not return any json data 
I further analysed that there is a option called validator.But it is denoted as a callable.And am not sure how to use that.

I am stuck here any help will be much helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088723/validation-library-for-node-js

Comment: @RachelGallen:I guess node-validator does not have any function to check if data is proper xml or not

Comment: no, but there's tons of them on git-hub

Comment: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules#wiki-parsers-xml

Answer (score 2):

I've attempted a grunt xml validator plugin using libxmljs, you shuld give it a try :)

https://www.npmjs.org/package/libxmljs

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-xml-validator